# Response is Null when I use JsonObject in retrofit

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit, retrofit2

When I use JsonObject as response in retrofit my output is:   `response: {}`

Here is my code with JsonObject response:

```
mCall=apiService.Check_App_Version("api/check-app-version/1/"+Utility.Get_App_Version(context));
        mCall.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response) {
                Log.e("response",""+response.body().toString()+" "+response.code());

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR",t.toString());
            }
        });
```

But when I use Object as the response in retrofit my output is:

```
response: {data=[{result=1.0, is_necessary=0.0}]}
```

and here is code for this:

```
mCall=apiService.Check_App_Version("api/check-app-version/1/"+Utility.Get_App_Version(context));
        mCall.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
                Log.e("response",""+response.body().toString()+" "+response.code());

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR",t.toString());
            }
        });
```

I want to use it as JsonObject. where is my mistake?

Comment: check this https://github.com/marcinOz/Retrofit2JSONConverterFactory

Answer (score 0):

Please use GsonConverterFactory to get parsed response in your desired object and if you want String response with Retrofit, use ScalarsConverterFactory. You can add both factories at the same time.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES).addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    if (retrofit == null) {
        String baseUrl = "http://example.com/";
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
```